# How to use foreignkey with different models in DJango

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-generic-relations

I'm stack with this problem, and looking for some solution before asking this question here. Lets say I have a one `Model` that shares same field in different `Models` how can I achieve this that when I get the `objects` of those `Models` I can include that `Model` `foreign key`, I did try to achieve this using `Generic Relation` in `DJango` yet it didn't solve my issue.

here is the sample what I'm trying to achieve using `Generic Relation`:

```
Model1(models.Model):
 .. objects_on_this_model ..

Model2(models.Model):
 .. objects_on_this_model ...

# Now this is where the model I could save different models with same field shared
SameObjectModel(models.Model):
 content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 object_id = models.PositiveIntengerField()
 content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
 .. objects_on_this_model .. # which is the field that has same field to use in different models
```

So when I try to get the `objects` from `Model(n)` how can I achieve or get the `SameObjectModel`?

I have this on my mind that I could do this:

```
Model(n).objects.prefetch_related('fk').all()
```

Seems it is not a good idea, since I do not know where I should put the `related_name` since the foreign key is the `content_type` which is the model and there is the `object_id` represent the field `primary_key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `Model(n)`'s you can add a `GenericRelation` to `SameObjectModel`:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation


class Model1(models.Model):
    sameobject = GenericRelation(SameObjectModel)
```

With this, it should be possible to use `prefetch_related`:

```
Model1.objects.prefetch_related('sameobject').all()
```

Comment: I will try this one, but where did you get the `prefetch_related` name or should I use `related_query_name`?

Comment: It's the name of the `GenericRelation` field from `Model1`

Comment: `related_query_name` is for when accessing `Model1` from `SameObjectModel`

Comment: Glad to help. Have fun!